# Most relevant word for numerical "order"

Tags: word-request, vocabulary, mathematics

What word in latin would be the best representation of the 'order' or 'cardinality' of a mathematical 'group' or 'set' respectively. I'm looking to translate "Finite Simple Group of Order 2[/Two]" into classical latin. In this context, it seems that it would mean the *size of* the set rather than the *number of elements in* it. I'm considering **magnitūdō**, **mēnsūra**, and **numerus** (just their singular nominative forms, because I don't need any hints on how to translate, but rather what word to use) as candidates, but I realise there may be a better alternative that I do not fully grasp the cultural connotations of the usage of these words.

Thank you!

Comment: Great question! Out of curiosity, are you translating that as an isolated phrase or in connection to something else? There is also a [nice song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BipvGD-LCjU) by that name. // For those not in the know: A "finite simple group of order two" is something of a running joke, a very complicated way of saying a simple thing. It is a good exercise in algebra to figure out what the group is.

Comment: It is simply an isolated phrase. I'm studying Latin, and I heard that song, and it inspired me to attempt a translation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, "order" in this context is conventional or idiomatic: it's used at this point because it's always been used that way.

In this case, I'd suggest ***ōrdō***. Not only is it a decent translation of the English (in the sense of "methodical arrangement, ordering"), but it'll be immediately clear to mathematicians that the "order" is meant.

EDIT: As Joonas and C.M. Weimer have suggested in the comments, it may also be more idiomatic to use an ordinal number (ba-dum *tsss*). So instead of *ōrdō duō* "order two", perhaps *ōrdō secundus* "second order". That would make the full phrase something like *grex fīnītus simplex ōrdinis secundī* "finite simple group of the second order".

Comment: I agree that *ordo* is a good choice here. I might add that it sounds better to me to translate from "second order" than "order two". But as far as I know, there is no canonical modern mathematical Latin.

Comment: I'll second *ordo secundus*.